# Can one optical fibre transmit multiple networks

Tags: optics

Can a single optic fibre installation transmit multiple connections,

For example, There are two networks, each network sends and receives data to or from. My question is can both the two networks be transmitted through a wired optic fibre?

Please correct me if am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't really understand what you are asking. A fiber is a layer-1 link and it will transmit network traffic. It doesn't matter the what the source or destination addresses are on the layer-3 packets; the fiber neither knows or cares what network traffic it carries.

What matters is that you use routers. Routers route traffic between networks. You terminate the fiber with a router on each end, and use a routing protocol between the routers to share routes between the routers.

Comment: Oh please correct me if am wrong, so that means any amount of network traffic can be transmitted as long as the fiber can handle it? 
On the end of the fiber can there be multiple routers? or it's only one router that should route the traffic to corresponding networks

Comment: A single fiber link (usually two fibers: one for transmit, and one for receive) will have one router on each end, but a router can have links to other routers, so that you can have unlimited networks on each end. That is how networks, including the Internet works.

Comment: Crystal clear! your a genius Sir.

Comment: I'd add that there are ways to share fibre which are not routing. Foreign wavelengths in Wave Division Multiplexing are extensively used by telcos and large ISPs wishing to share fibre optical links.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it can do it in a number of different ways.

One fibre can carry multiple different wavelengths of light.

Each of those wavelengths of light may carry multiple different logical network connections.

And each of those logical network connections may carry packets between multiple different source and destination networks.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a single optic fibre installation transmit multiple connections

Short answer: yes.

The long answer depends on what you really mean. The basic options are (expanding on @PeterGreen's answer)

### Physical layer

An optical link on the physical layer can be multiplexed using wavelength-division multiplex (WDM). That way, you can can even run incompatible protocols concurrently, e.g. Ethernet and Fibre Channel, with independent link speeds and bandwidth.

If there's only a single strand of fiber you need to use wavelength-division duplex (WDD) for a generally bilateral network link, limiting the use of WDM.

### Data link layer

If you connect the link between switches, nodes on both sides can communicate with each other directly. Using VLAN trunking, you can run multiple independent and separated networks across, albeit with the same L2 protocol like Ethernet, and all sharing the link bandwidth.

### Network layer

Connecting the link between routers, you can route between any number of networks on each side. The routers need to use either static routes or share a routing protocol like OSPF.

In a more complex setup, you can combine any of those variants.